# deleting object elements from array using splice react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add and delete an obect from an array, I have been able to figure out the add object part, but the deletion is not working. I have used filter() but it did nothing. Now I am using splice, it works but it deletes the first element, instead of the selected item. below is a sample code, and I have shown only the functions for better clarity.

```
        handleDelete(item) {

          this.setState(({ list}) => {
            const newList = [...list];
            newList.splice(item.key, 1);
            console.log('deleted', newList);
            return { list: newList };
          });
        }


        handleAdd() {
          const { firstname, lastname, email, phone} = this.state;
          const ID = uuid();
          const newItemObject = {
              key: ID,
              firstname: firstname,
              lastname: lastname,
              email: email,
              phone: phone,
              image: null,
          };

          this.setState(prevState => ({
            list: [...prevState.list, newItemObject]
          }));
        }
```

I would like to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The item's key and index in the array are probably not the same. If the item is in the array, you can use `Array.indexOf()` to find it's index, and splice it out:

```
handleDelete(item) {
  this.setState(({ list }) => {
    const newList = [...list];
    const index = newList.indexOf(item);
    newList.splice(index, 1);

    return {
      list: newList
    };
  });
}
```

Or if you want to use `Array.filter()`, check if the key of of current element (`o`) is different from that of `item`:

```
handleDelete(item) {
  this.setState(({ list }) => ({
    list: list.filter(o => o.key !== item.key)
  }))
}
```

Comment: many thanks, both methods worked.
but which is better to use?

Comment: The filter method is shorter and concise, and doesn't create another redundant array (the removed items from slice). I would use filter.

Comment: have another question, but i dont know if its proper to ask another question under a different question thread

Comment: The comments are used to discussion the specific question/answer. Create a new question.